# curl with php return messed up string

Tags: php, curl

I tried using cURL in php to fetch a xml file, the url is http://game1-cbt.ma.sdo.com:10001/connect/app/exploration/fairyhistory?cyt=1, but the returning string is messed up. I googled and I tried curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');, but it still doesn't work. The content showed up didn't change. Here is my full program

```
$url = "http://game1-cbt.ma.sdo.com:10001/connect/app/exploration/fairyhistory";
$ua="Million/100 (m0; m0xx; 4.2.2) samsung/m0xx/m0:4.2.2/JDQ39/I9300XXUFME3:user/release-keys";
$cookies = "S=85g158t9j3t4hi6kmcf47rbjh1";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookies);

$r = curl_exec($c);

echo $r;
```

update:

it works with the line with UA commented. Thank you all!

PS：
the UA is from a package I captured from a mobile online game，I'm trying to simulate the actions of the game.

Comment: Remove CURLOPT_USERAGENT and try

Comment: Can you include the "messed up" xml returned?

Comment: Should the url variable have the '?cyt=1' part of the url?

Comment: What's `Million/100` as the user agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "http://game1-cbt.ma.sdo.com:10001/connect/app/exploration/fairyhistory";
$ua = "Million/100 (m0; m0xx; 4.2.2) samsung/m0xx/m0:4.2.2/JDQ39/I9300XXUFME3:user/release-keys";
$cookies = "S=85g158t9j3t4hi6kmcf47rbjh1";
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
//curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua); - you don't need this
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
$r = curl_exec($c);

echo $r;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua);`  is going Bad in this code Remove it,
Better use another UA

and its working in my test if removed `curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$ua);`,

**Note if you Directly echo this in a browser check Source (View Source) to conform**